# Hosting wordpress Images in a sub-domain when my wordpress is installed in a subdomain

Tags: image, wordpress, subdomain

I have a gallery for my website (mysite.com) as a sub-domain (gallery.mysite.com) but I want to host my wordpress Images in another sub-domain (images.gallery.mysite.com) I have changes the **"Full URL path to files"** but wordpress is not uploading the images to the folder how can I fix this or are there any other solutions, because I wand to speed up the load time of my site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand if, you want wordpress to upload the file into another location other than the default one. if this is the case, take a look at [Editing the default image/file upload location of WordPress!](http://www.reviewsaurus.com/tips-tricks/editing-the-default-imagefile-upload-location-of-wordpress/)